# Update MySQL View from datagridview c#

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have a `table1` with columns (id(pk) ,formation,matricule(fk)) and `table2` with columns(matricule(pk) ,name) which is created in test MySQL  database.

Then I created a view with (matricule,name,formation ).

When I insert data in `table1` from MySQL it save data in view at the same time . I called the view in datagridview c# ,  when I try to insert data from it to `table1` it save data only in the `table1` and not in the view, when I update the datagridview it only shows column (matricule,formation ) and  name empty !!

This is the code I tried

```
private void insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String constring = "datasource=;port=3306;username=;password=";

        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
        {
            conn.Open();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)// picks data from dataGridview                
            {

                try   // MySql connection
                {


                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                    cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

                    if (row.IsNewRow) continue;
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test.table1(matricule,formation)VALUES(@matricule,@formation)";

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@matricule", row.Cells[0].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@formation", row.Cells[1].Value);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("data inserted.");
                    //dataGridView2.Update();

        //update
            string query = "SELECT * FROM test.table1";
        // should i replace it with  "select * test.view ; ??
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
           MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();

           // DataView dv = new DataView(dt); should i use dataview ?? 
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView.DataSource = da;
                }



                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }

            }


        }
    }
```

how can I update the view in MySQL from datagridview c# ???

Comment: A View is really just a stored query NOT a separate table - so you when you insert data to table1 it is not saving _"data in view at the same time"_. As per your comment you need to use ""select * test.view;" to requery the view.

Comment: Could you mention the query that you used to create the view?

Comment: you can not modife a join view !!  mean you can not  use "insert into database.View (column) value ( data ) ; "

Comment: Check table2 has relevant data against matricule(fk)

Comment: @vipin CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `admtds`@`tntimtds1` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `test`.`view` AS
    select 
        `t`.`matricule` AS `matricule`,
        `t`.`formation` AS `formation`,
        `n`.`nom` AS `nom`
    from
        (`test`.`table1` `t`
        join `test`.`tabel2` `n` ON ((`t`.`id` = `n`.`matricule`)))

Comment: i want to update data in view at the  same time i insert data  in table from c#!! i thought it simple like in mysql it save automaticaly in the view but its not !!!

Comment: I think your condition is wrong , change it from  ON ((t.id = n.matricule) to  ON ((n.id = t.matricule).

Comment: no its not , it works when i insert data from mysql  and save at the same time in table and view , but the problem is when i insert data from c# datagrid , it only insert in table and not in view